# Хочу проверить правильность своего краткого конспекта по определенному языку

Tags: обсуждение

Это очень важно, так как я это буду учить наизусть(большую часть недавно выучил, но есть время на то, чтобы кое-что "подредактировать" в памяти). Конспект действительно мал, лишь свойства ключевых слов и иногда описание того, где они применяются, ничего более. Где мне задать такой "вопрос"?

Comment: Цель какая? Сдать экзамен? Пройти собеседование?

Comment: @AK Учиться программировать. Для того, чтобы уметь программировать, нужно ведь точно знать, что такое обратный вызов, интерфейс, абстрактный класс, не так ли?

Comment: Некоторые языки программирования предполагают, что вам достаточно знать минимальные основы и кнопку F1. Кстати, некоторые работодатели считают так же.

Answer (score 5):

> Для того, чтобы уметь программировать, нужно ведь точно знать, что такое обратный вызов, интерфейс, абстрактный класс, не так ли?

Думаю, что такой способ плохо работает. Вы когда-то научились говорить на русском языке, не зная, что такое слово, предложение, подлежащее и сказуемое. Вместо этого вы много практиковались.

С программированием так же: пишите код, читайте чужой код, найдите ментора, который будет исправлять ваши ошибки. Изучайте теорию для решения конкретной задачи, которая у вас прямо сейчас есть. Тогда вы усвоите эту теорию.

Хороший учебный курс на этом и строится: кусочки теории и много практических задач, которые основаны на этой теории.

Учить наизусть может быть полезно только чтобы сдать экзамен. В работе заученное наизусть бесполезно совсем, вообще, абсолютно.

А для проверки конспекта наверняка сработает такой способ:

1. выложить конспект в Google Docs,
2. открыть доступ на комментирование,
3. кинуть ссылку в чат с просьбой проверить (+1 к [ответу АК](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9721/181472))

Answer (score 2):

Я бы задал вопрос в чате, причём желательно в чате с теми людьми, которые разбираются в этом языке.

Из своего опыта скажу, что с год-полтора назад я занимался похожим: хотел подтянуть знание C# (того, что нужно по работе) и [обсуждал](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35076958#35076958) в [чате по csharp на ru so](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--).

Мне правда быстро указали на то, что многие темы, которые я считаю важными для работы -- важно на моей конкретной работе, а где-то совершенно не важны.

На основном сайте такой вопрос будет скорее всего бесполезен для базы знаний, а также бесполезен и для других спрашивающих (см. выше что я писал про свой опыт). Вероятнее всего его закроют как "необходимо перефразировать для получения конкретного и чёткого ответа", хотя думаю, что минусовать особо не будут. (Возможно даже успеете получить ценные для вас лично комментарии или ответы)

В остальном же нужно понимать, что учиться программировать зависит от знания конкретного языка на менее чем 10%. Вот я например, по вебу знаю только языков программирования пять штук (html, css, js, c#, sql) и врать не буду -- знаю не на все 100%, хотя что-то знаю на достаточно глубоком уровне. А кроме этого есть ещё понимание типовых структур данных (не всегда зависит от конкретного языка) и алгоритмов, в т.ч. и ходовых паттернов/принципов (тоже не сильно завязано на конкретный язык).

Так что как один из шагов к цели -- это полезно, но не концентрируйтесь только на этом одном.

Comment: У меня как раз конспект по штукам, которые есть примерно во всех языках. И реализация если и разнится, то совсем чуть чуть. Возьмем пару из них на пример: обратный вызов и абстрактный класс. Суть обратного вызова абсолютно та же во всех языка. Суть абстрактного класса - та же во всех языках. Именно это я и учу. Совсем основы. Однако спасибо, замечание о том, что есть некие универсальные знания очень важно, учту при своем обучении.

Comment: То есть, резюмируя, - задавать вопросы на эту тематику нужно в специализированных чатах на этом сайте, да? Не будет ли это невежливо с порога давать людям краткий конспект, мол, проверьте? Это меня и смущает.

Comment: эх, а чата по java нет.

Comment: @Miron, потому что java никому не нужна :)

Comment: @Grundy все, отправляю жалобу на ваш комментарий в связи с его "грубостью и унизительностью" >:)

Answer (score 2):

Практика **(!!)** лучше всего заменит любой конспект.

Я когда свой первый язык программирования учил (по книгам и форумам), старался протыкать на компьютере все те кнопки, которые в книгах описываются, каждую последовательность действий выполнить **сам** (и еще раз повторить), по нескольку раз переписывал одни и те же велосипеды - изучал новые методы.

Лучше всего найти какую-либо задачу (или самому придумать, если ничего не находится), где бы можно было применить все свои знания. Потом репозиторий с решением можно будет в резюме воткнуть.

Задачи очень хорошо находятся на работе **(!!)**, ну или тестовые задания при устройстве на работу, ну или в описаниях вакансий на худой конец можно список необходимых технологий почерпнуть.

Comment: Для начала, примем за аксиомы утверждения "чем больше мы используем некоторое знание, тем лучше оно запоминается", "то, что запомнил, забыть очень сложно", "не использующиеся знания со временем затираются". На практике мы во-первых можем не до конца понять функционал некой штуки, хуже - мы можем понять его неправильно(см 2 аксиому)! Во-вторых, если мы и поймем правильно, то мы не можем гарантировать регулярное повторение(оно позволяет запомнить знания как можно дешевле)(см 1 и 3 аксиому). Более того, мы их можем некоторый период не использовать(см 3 аксиому).

Comment: Именно поэтому я и стремлюсь сделать конспект с очень краткими формулировками важных моментов. Тем более я могу засунуть их в программу для интервального повторения, и тогда я смогу запомнить их на всю жизнь.

Comment: Да я года 2 как пишу(с перерывами). Не лучшая это стратегия - исключительно практика. Интервальное повторение необходимо. Забыл упомянуть самое важное - вы теряете некоторые  детали знания, когда проходит время. Поэтому важно помнить точные формулировки. Учил я 3-4 месяца назад абстрактные классы и интерфейсы - только сейчас мало, что помню. Только вообще банальности.

Comment: @Miron Через 3-4 месяца Вы забываете какие-то технологии просто потому что не пользуетесь ими. Зачем тогда учить то, что не нужно? Несомненно, Вы должны знать основы. Но углублённо изучать что-то, IMHO, необходимо только при наличии практики. Тогда, кстати, у Вас и не останется вопросов о правильности выводов, потому что Вы самостоятельно их подтвердите.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Насчет ошибочности выводов не могу согласиться, так как вы можете думать, что что-то происходит по одной причине, но в действительности это происходит по другой причине.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Я не против практики. Я лишь за следующий подход - сначала создаем точные формулировки(как только полностью поймем тему), которые заучиваем. Затем идем практиковаться. Вот и все.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Не хотелось бы мне потерять знания, просто их не применяя некоторое время. Некоторые вещи применяются ситуативно - вот почему это нужно учить. Вы эти вещи банально забудете. А тонкости уж подавно уйдут из вашей головы(см "самое важное"). Поэтому тупо надежней и дешевле мой подход с интервальными повторениями всех кратких формулировок.